# LenovoIdeapad s400 Ubuntu 17.04 battery and Acpi issue

Tags: lenovo, battery, acpi

I am very new to linux ubuntu. I just changed from windows 8.1 to ubuntu 17.04 completely and tadaam problems started. My battery was charging only until 59% then I tried some fixes but now I can not boot my laptop on battery. I have to plug in my AC charger to turn my laptop on. With some solution I read on internet i thought i have some kind of acpi problem but I my terminal says acpi not found. I dont know here can I download acpi. This is the status of my battery;

upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0

native-path:          (null)
  power supply:         no
  updated:              Do 01 Jan 1970 01:00:00 CET (1495714310 seconds ago)
  has history:          no
  has statistics:       no
  unknown
    warning-level:       unknown
    icon-name:          '(null)'

I am using Lenovo ideapad s400 Intel core i5.

Please could some body help me? or I should go back to windows :(

Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

To find the path to your battery use the following command:

```
upower -e
```

This will output:

```
/org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT{#}
```

Now run:

```
 upower -i {battery path}
```

This will output full battery information, check the capacity percentage. Not sure what fixes you did so far so cannot guess as to what could cause it not to boot up on battery only.

---

To install something in terminal, you type:

```
sudo apt-get install {package name}
```